# Is it possible to automate creating a new branch, forking the repo to local, replace a string in all files in subfolders and create pull request?

Tags: git, replace, automation, bitbucket, git-fork

Automate repo fork, replace and create PR

Am a total newbie and have not really tried anything yet. My requirement on bitbucket is to automate below process:

1. Create a new branch from existing branch (not master)
2. Fork the repository
3. Find and replace string "ABC" with "xyz" in all files matching filename  "*.XML" in all subfolders
4. Raise a pull request with default reviewers to merge changes to the remote branch

There is a limitation in the repository and we cannot directly make changes on the remote branch. Forking is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole world of Bitbucket API endpoints, you may want to check it out https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/